# Killall behaves differently in Ubuntu 16 and Rapberry Pi OS

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

According to the documentation of killall, both in Ubuntu 16 (psmisc version 22.21-2.1ubuntu0.1) and in Raspbian Pi OS (psmisc version 23.2.1):

> If a command name is longer than 15 characters, the full name may be
> unavailable (i.e.  it is swapped out).  In this case, killall will
> kill everything that matches within the first 15 characters.

I have a command name let's say command-name-longer.

In Ubuntu this works (even the command name is longer than 15 characters):

```
killall command-name-longer
```

In Raspbian doesn't work and I have to use:

```
killall command-name-lo
```

I'm trying to find a way to use the same command on both platform to kill processes with names longer than 15 characters. I cannot use `pkill` as an alternative because it does not feature the option `-o` (older than)